# What is the time complexity of the fastest HTML parsing algorithm? I need it in Big O notation

Tags: algorithm, parsing

As the title says, I need to know the time complexity of the fastest HTML parsing algorithm.

**UPDATE:** I need the complexity of creating DOM tree from HTML code, not just parsing it.

Comment: What did your own research turn out so far?

Comment: I would guess that the parsing can be done in linear time, as SAX parsers typically scan the input document sequentially.

Comment: Hint: can a deterministic automaton with a stack can do it? If so, its runtime is linear.

Comment: @Codor: virtually all parsers read the source file sequentially.  By itself, that doesn't make then linear time.  Imagine a parser that spends 2^N cycles processing the Nth character.  (That's a stupid parser, but it contradicts your argument).

Comment: @amit I know that tokenizing an input in every language can be done in linear time using a NFA or DFA that is converted to code. But I need the complexity of doing systax analyzing, semantic analyzing and finally create the DOM tree from document.

Comment: In big O relatively to what? Number of elements, characters, ...?

Comment: @Oriol relative to characters

Comment: Does `<script>document.write(document.body.outerHTML.repeat(1e5))</script>` count only as 68 characters? Then you have a problem, because it will insert a massive amount of contents.

Comment: @Oriol yes, it counts only 68 characters. In my case, it does not matter. I don't want to execute or even render the code. I just want to analyze some structures of the code. I use the AngleSharp package to parse html code, and want to know at which complexity it can do (if it uses the best algorithm). There is no document about it in it's repository, even in Performance page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML DOM construction should be linear time on properly nested input. However, the Html5 algorithm, which AngleSharp  claims to implement, requires specific handling of improperly nested content, by way of the so-called "adoption agency algorithm" (AAA), which requires a linear search through a stack of unclosed formatting elements. Although there is an attempt to limit the damage (see [this W3C discussion thread](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2010Sep/0137.html) for some history), it is possible to craft an HTML document for which the algorithm takes quadratic time.